# Optimizar UPDATE de SQL SERVER en C# para muchos registros

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

mi pregunta es la siguiente, tengo dos tablas las cuales con los datos de una tengo que actualizar la otra tabla o insertarlos si no existen, hasta normal, la cuestión es que son mas de 400000 datos los que tengo que actualizar y pues esto tarda demasiado tiempo y esta tarea tengo que real izarla cada 12 horas porque la información se actualiza en ese periodo de tiempo.

Esta es mi consulta SQL que tengo, solo es el esquema de la consulta, no tengo agregado el update ni el insert respectivamente, por ahora solo estoy buscando si el dato de una tabla existe en la otra.

[image: Consulta SQL]

Este es mi código en C#

[image: Código C#]

El PlacaVentaLista() es solo una consulta a la tabla con los datos nuevos
un select * from [tabla]

como ven, la consulta SQL se ejecuta muchas veces para poder hacer la comparación con cada dato de las tablas, mi pregunta es como puedo lograr reducir el tiempo de ejecución de todas esta consultas SQL

Comment: Todo esto deberia ser un SP en la db.

Comment: Que pena la pregunta, a que te refieres con un SP? un procedimiento almacenado?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que sigues pensando fila por fila, en vez de pensar en conjuntos. SQL Server se encarga de manejar las filas de la mejor forma y sólo tienes que decirle que haga con el conjunto.
Aquí hay un ejemplo a grandes rasgos de lo que requieres.

```
UPDATE des SET
   columna1 = ori.columna1,
   columna2 = ori.columna2,
   ...
   columnaN = ori.columnaN
FROM TablaDestino des
JOIN TablaOrigen ori ON des.ID = ori.ID

INSERT INTO TablaDestino
SELECT * FROM TablaOrigen ori
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM TablaDestino des WHERE des.ID = ori.ID)
```

También puedes usar la instrucción `MERGE`, pero con esa he tenido problemas de rendimiento.

Comment: Amigo gracias por tu respuesta, y el consejo de pensar en conjuntos jeje, realizare unos ajustes al insert para que me funcione en mi bd